# How to draw a shaded approximation curve

Tags: python, dataframe

In the data in test.csv, I'd like to do the following with the values in the Time column as the x-axis and the values in the A_x column (x=1,2,3) as the data on the y-axis.

・Draw an approximate curve from each of the three types of data.

・Draw the value of column A_xsd (x=1,2,3) as standard deviation, not as an error bar but as a shadow.

However, due to my lack of knowledge, I'm only halfway through. I'd be grateful if someone could give me some correct answer. Thank you very much.
(This is a simplified version of the original data more than 1000 lines)

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', header = None)

x1 = df['Time'] 
y1 = df['A_1']
x2 = df['Time']
y2 = df['A_2']
x3 = df['Time']
y3 = df['A_3']

sd1 = df['A_1sd'] 
sd2 = df['A_1sd']
sd3 = df['A_1sd']

fig = plt.figure()
ax.set_xlim(0, 5)  
ax.set_ylim(0, 150)  
ax.set_xlabel("Time", fontsize=10)  
ax.set_ylabel("OD600", fontsize=10)  

ax.grid()  
ax.tick_params(labelsize=10)
```

#### test.csv

```
Time,A_1,A_1sd,A_2,A_2sd,A_3,A_3sd
1,6,76,23159,125,23239,40
2,20,85,22709,99,22809,50
3,46,20,22629,89,22749,62
4,12,81,22729,85,22859,86
5,1,75,23029,90,23219,112
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the three data columns has a range very different from the other two, so we should use subplots. You could use a loop to create the same kind of subplot for each of the three data columns.

The shading can be done with matplotlib's [`fill_between()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html) method:

```py
x = df.Time

fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 1, sharex=True)

for n in (1, 2, 3):
    y = eval('df.A_' + str(n))
    sd = eval('df.A_' + str(n) + 'sd')
    ax[n-1].plot(x, y)
    ax[n-1].fill_between(x, y - sd, y + sd, alpha=0.3)
```

[image: shaded curves]